# How to implement a generic method to get data from database with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have generic method for add, update and delete entities. But I also want to use generics for retrieving data.

Here is my methods to get data:

```
public static List<ClassA> getAllClassAData() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ClassA.class);
    return criteria.list();
}

public static List<ClassB> getAllClassBData() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ClassB.class);
    return criteria.list();
}

public static List<ClassC> getAllClassCData() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ClassC.class);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

I tried to make something like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> getAllData() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(???.class); //Here is where I'm stuck
    return criteria.list();
}
```

And I stuck with passing the class as arg for criteria creation:

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Generic.class);
```

How can I make JVM know what class I'm trying to pass during criteria creation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your generic method should look more like :

```
public static <T> List<T> getAllData(Class<T> clazz) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

and you should invoke it like:

```
List<ClassA> list = getAllData(ClassA.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me as I wanted to. Btw, I use static context because I have several methods to communicate with DB and there's no need in DBUtil instance creation. At least I don't see the reason to do it in a small project.

Answer (score 2):

A simple step to simulate being dynamic is to pass the class instance on query. It looks ugly, but does the work. Unfortunately there is no way to do sth like `T.class`

```
public static <T> List<T> getAllData(Class<T> klass) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(klass);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly static and generics dont mix well, so you will have to do away with static.

Next have a look at how this is handled here ,
https://github.com/sajit/Webgearz/blob/master/src/main/java/com/webgearz/tb/daos/impl/AbstractMongoDao.java

```
protected Class<N> persistentClass;

        public Class<N> getPersistentClass() {
                return persistentClass;
        }
```

and related classes. That should help what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look over the generic repository pattern, it is used a lot in c# and although the generics are not the same in Java you should be able to do normal generic runtime hacks to get the underlying type.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-2cplusdoneplusright